# How to do nested Django SELECT?

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    from_friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_set')
    to_friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_friend_set')
```

I'd like to SELECT all to_friends that have from_friend = a certain User.

Then, I'd like to pass to_friends to inside filter in another .objects.filter(). Is this the way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pccardune says, you get the relevant users like this:

```
friendships = Friendship.objects.filter(from_friend=some_user)
```

But in fact you can pass this directly into your next query:

```
second_select = Whatever.objects.filter(friend__in=friendships)
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to `SELECT` all `to_friends` that have `from_friend` = a certain User.

You could get all the Friendship objects for this step like so:

```
friendships = Friendship.objects.filter(from_friend=some_user)
```

Then you can get all the to_friend fields into a flat list using the values_list method of a query set:

```
friends = friendships.values_list("to_friend", flat=True)
```

At this point `friends` is a ValuesListQuery object that works just like a list.  You can iterate over the friends and use the values in other filter() calls.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to return the desired results

```
User.objects.filter(to_friend_set__from_friend=1)
```